# git не работает post-receive

Tags: git, ssh, githooks

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь настроить деплой сайта с помощью гит по [инструкции](http://ruhighload.com/post/Git+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)
вот только когда на локальном компьютере выполняю **git push production master** то сам сайт не обновляется. Решил выполнить команду sh post-receive из консоли в ручную, комнда выполняется успешно и изменения для сайта применяются. Сделал вывод, что не по каким то причинам не запускается скрипт post-receive после завершения push`а.

Подскажите пожалуйста, у кого какие соображения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверьте что:

1. У вашего сценария есть право на запуск - он запускается просто по имени, без `sh`
2. Что для теста вы использовали тот же логин, с которого делаете `push`

Comment: _У вашего сценария есть право на запуск - он запускается просто по имени, без sh_ - да, без sh скрипт не выполняется, получается я не могу давать право на выполнение скрипту, теперь сижу мучаю техподдержку хостинга.
Спасибо!